# where is the configuration for https host Django+PHP

Tags: linux, php, django, hosts

I am an app developer, with little web site development experience,
now having to check some work on a virtual server, All seems to be working fine, but I cannot find where a configuration for a host is [this work was done by a sys admin that is on holiday, so meanwhile I just need some really basic configurations, that if pointed the location I can figure out],

So the server works with Django and PHP,
there is already a website on Django, I can see that the host for this site is configured on

```
$/etc/hosts
```

like this:

```
106.187.93.147  applounge.com.au
```

The problem is that, there is an https hello world sites that I cannot seem to find the host configuration for,

```
https://106.187.93.147/tests/hello.html
```

So, where can I find this https configuration?

as noted the hosting works with Django and PHP,
so in PHP the configuration should be on?

```
$/etc/httpd
```

But there is no such a folder on my $/etc

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can pretty much be on any location, but the default paths to check would be `/var/www/html` or `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

If it's in neither one, try finding that `hello.html` file for further clues:

```
find / -name hello.html
```

The path where that resides should reveal the `DocumentRoot` and you can then search your server for files containing that path, for instance:

```
grep -ir '/path/to/docroot' /etc
```